# ADFS confusion over terminology - Relaying Party

Tags: amazon-web-services, adfs

Hi guys I’m trying to implement ADFS with one of the applications I’m working at, but I think I’m a little confused about some of the terminology used.

So far I thought that when the browser tries to access the SP, an auth request - from the SP - is sent to the IDP which reads it and the STS at that end, if everything goes well, issues a token and sends it back to the SP.

But now, something else seems to have cropped up, a relying party that is, which I haven’t come across in my research – and I’ve prowled through an awful lot of documentation.

So, back on the research side of things, the way I understand it is that there is an STS at the IDP’s end, but there is also another STS at the SP’s end - the relying party STS, and this second STS reads the claim issued by the first STS. From this it seems to follows that the Relaying Party, is nothing else than the SP itself. Did I get this right? If so, considering that my SP is hosted on AWS, does it mean that my Relying party STS needs to be installed on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

For SAML-P, the application is a SP.

For WS-Fed, the application is a RP.

You can chain ADFS together e.g.

Application --> ADFS-RP --> ADFS

In this scenario. the middle ADFS just passes data through so it is referred to as an ADFS-RP i.e. an ADFS that you do not authenticate against.

Comment: right, so if I understand this correctly in SAML you don't need the relying party

Comment: In SAML, the RP is normally called a SP.